# I can't click or edit my button opened jframe

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have a jtable in second jframe (calisanEkrani) and I want those table informations printed to the third jframe (guvenliksorusturmaformu). I got the printing part and I made a button to open the third jframe but I can't focus (click or edit anything) and close the frame without closing the second.

How can I make the third jframe appear focused, editable (jtextfield) and when closed, comes back to the second frame?

This is the button action in calisanEkrani:

```
private void formcikartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                
    guvenliksorusturmaformu gf = new guvenliksorusturmaformu();
    guvenliksorusturmaformu.form_adsoyad.setText(this.ad_alani.getText()); 
    guvenliksorusturmaformu.form_departman.setText(this.dept_alani.getText());
    guvenliksorusturmaformu.form_maas.setText(this.maas_alani.getText());
    gf.setVisible(true);
    }
```

I want the guvenliksorusturmaformu frame on top and clickable. I can't even press 'X' to close it. It makes windows error sound and flashes but I can still play with the calisanEkrani (second jframe).

(Not very good at English so basic explanation or just the code will be good)

Comment: how exactly did you link that method to the button? you're aware that that is not a valid implementation of the ActionListener interface's method?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean, I'm new to these. I just wanted the button open a jframe and put information on it and it worked. I just can't click, edit or close it.

Comment: so basically, you just write some random code and you magically hope it'll work?

Comment: Of course not I'm trying to learn as you can see. I tried lot while making the information pass to other frames and this is the result.

Comment: your method for the 'button action', how do you link it to the button? I see no reason at all why (or how) that method should be triggered when you click a button

Comment: I performed an action from Netbeans swing desing. So I think what you asked is automatic. I made the textfields public static in guvenliksorusturmaformu so it can write inside. So this is working, writes to textfields and opens it.

Comment: "So I think what you asked is automatic", that might be your problem. Don't rely on the netbeans editor, the code it generates is very hard to read, and practically impossible to maintain without introducing regression bugs. Check if the method you posted is actually called. This method will not be automatically called if you click a button.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: *How can I make the third jframe appear focused, editable (jtextfield) and when closed, comes back to the second frame?* - don't use a second frame. Instead you should be using a `modal JDialog`. Focus will automatically be placed on the dialog when you make it visible and when it is closed focus will automatically go back to the parent frame.

Comment: @camickr I was thinking about 'what will happen if it was a jdialog' but I gave up because it was frustrating. Thanks to you I wanted to try it and I add somethings by looking up, it is working now. Thank you!